# Is it possible to charge a large 30,000uF capacitor to 250V in 5 seconds?

Tags: capacitor, integrated-circuit, battery-charging, charging, supercapacitor

The energy of the capacitor would be E = (1/2)*C*V^2 = (1/2) * (30000 * (10^-6)) * (250^2) = 937.5 J

That would be 937.5 J / 5s = 187.5 W

If I had a 12V power supply then the current would be 187.5W / 12V = 16A

I was looking at the LT3751 integrated circuit that charges capacitors up to 500V but I am unsure about how to size the other components (transformer, MOSFET, diodes) or even if it is possible with the LT3751.

Are there other ICs that can achieve this current draw or other circuits which would take power more directly from the mains for the application of charging a large capacitor to high voltages quickly?

Edit:
I found a TI reference design for a power supply that can supply 250W at 30V. (https://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidryy6/tidryy6.pdf?ts=1645134917413) and that wouldn't be compatible on the V_TRANS pin (max rating = 24V).

I would like to keep the control of starting and stopping the charging of the capacitor with the CHARGE pin and was wondering if there is a version of the LT3750 that has max voltage pin ratings on pins in the >30 V range

Comment: The LT3751 has a detailed design procedure in its datasheet that outlines how to choose the component values. You can of course do it with that chip. Though you might want to choose a higher input voltage, i.e. 48V, so you don't have to deal with such large currents.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can do a lot less than 5 seconds if you just stick the capacitor across a 250 V power supply (to be perfectly clear, *do not do this*). The LT3751 may not be able to do it alone though, going by the fact that you'd need about ten times the output current they use in the example circuitry; it may not be able to drive a beefy enough MOSFET. But it may be able to--I haven't looked into it that far, otherwise I would be writing an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Can be done with a 1.5 A DC current source under *ideal conditions*...any other method requires the charging source to accommodate higher current than 1.5 A at peak times.

Comment: Another question is what is the temperature rise expected for an EDLC electrode junction when exposed to a charge cycle of 5 s with 188 W of power as the DF and  Rja are often not given. But ESR and volume are given

Comment: EDLC are rated at limits for Arrhenius MTBF effects like 1000 h  at 60'C so sustained high temperatures contradict long life expectancy. This must be defined when asking , what is possible with what are the consequences if any to MTBF. This can be quantized by changes in ESR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it possible to charge a large 30,000uF capacitor to 250V in 5
> seconds?*

I have built a 2.5 farad (a stacked type with a balancing management system) charger that reaches 130 volts in thirty seconds so I don't see why not. Total energy stored is 21 kJ. That's an average power of 704 watts. It runs from a 40 volt DC source hence, average current is about 18 amps.

The circuit I used would charge a 30,000 μF capacitor in pretty quick time.

> *Are there other ICs that can achieve this current draw or other
> circuits*

To get the power levels I used home-spun parallel [Ćuk converters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%86uk_converter) operating in the 50 kHz to 150 kHz range. No specialist chips but quite specialized inductor cores that could handle high levels of intermittent saturation levels without their inductance levels falling through the floor.

I also used silicon carbide MOSFETs for another type that needed to charge 100 μF to around 1,000 volts is less than 5 ms. I'd strongly consider them for charging a big capacitor to 500 volts.

Comment: what kind of resources would you be willing to share about the silicon carbide mosfets? do you think I would be able to use them to charge the 30000uF Cap to 250 within 5 seconds?

Comment: @Erv You need to pick a device that has a maximum drain-source voltage of at least 650 volts. I'd be looking at a device from [this list](https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/semiconductors-discretes/fets/silicon-carbide-sic-mosfets-modules?brand=onsemi&transistor-polarity=n-channel&drain-source-voltage-vds=650v)

Comment: @Erv are we finished here. Have you considered accepting this answer?